# mongodb replicaset auth not working

Tags: mongodb, database-replication, replicaset

I have a problem with replica sets

After I add keyFile path to mongodb.conf I can connect, this is my mongo.conf:

```
logpath=/path/to/log

logappend=true

replSet = rsname

fork = true

keyFile = /path/to/key
```

And this is what is showed in the command line:

```
XXXX@XXXX:/etc$ sudo service mongodb restart
stop: Unknown instance:
mongodb start/running, process 10540
XXXX@XXXX:/etc$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
connecting to: test
Mon Sep 30 18:44:20.984 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect failed
XXXX@XXXX:/etc$
```

if I comment the keyFile line in mongo.conf it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the authentication would be the problem you should get a different message (and should be able to start the shell without the authenticated session just prevent you to run most of the commands).

This one means more like a socket exception that where you likely to connect there is no service listening. You can check with netstat if the process is listening that ip:port which is in the message. I assume that the mongod process have not started which can be for several reasons check the logs for the current one. One thing can be that the keyfile is not exists at the specified path or not the appropriate privileges have set on.

Adding a keyfile automaticly turns on the auth option too. This means you have to use a user to authenticate, but you can bypass this authentication with a localhost exception: . Read the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/#localhost-exception).

Answer (score 4):

I solve the problem.

It was related with the key file permissions, I fixed the permissionas and ownership and work like charm:

As a root user I did:

```
$ chmod 700 keyfile
$ chown monogdb:mongodb keyfile
```

Comment: May i ask why have not you accepted my answer and commented on that the wrong permissions were the problem as i mentioned?

Comment: I find this before your answer... but If you want the point, there you have, thanks.